# Bootstrap on click not for carousel not getting active src

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, carousel

I am trying to get the src of the active carousel element. It picks the initially active src and then never updates on subsequent clicks. 
I based my code on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25314539/how-to-get-bootstrap-carousel-next-image-src) question.

I've read about binding at run time but none of the suggested solutions have worked (eg adding .update after .click).

Here is my script:

```
   $('#myCarousel').on('click',function(event){
        var currslide = $('.active').find('img').attr('src');
        alert(currslide);         
   });
```

Here's my carousel HTML:

```
<!-- Carousel ================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-interval="false">
    <div id="theme-selecting" class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="1" id="r1" checked="checked" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r1">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/logo.png" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="2" id="r2" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r2">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/rain-drops.jpg" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="3" id="r3" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r3">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/rain-drops.jpg" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="4" id="r4" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r4">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/rain-drops.jpg" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="5" id="r5" checked="checked" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r5">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/rain-drops.jpg" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
                    <input type="radio" name="rGroup" value="6" id="r6" />
                    <label class="whatever text-center" for="r6">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="/images/rain-drops.jpg" alt="">
                        <h3>
                            Holiday</h3>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left fa-2x">
    </i></a><a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><i
        class="fa fa-chevron-right fa-2x"></i></a>
        <!--<ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active">/li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>   -->
</div>
<!-- End Carousel -->
```

Comment: Is there any way you could put up a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new#)?   From my [testing](http://www.bootply.com/3GqfZxaAYh) it is working fine and updates the src on click.  Note: For testing you must click the icon for desktop (right side) to get alerts to work.

Comment: Remember the `active` class is on the entire item row, not on individual images or radio buttons.  So it's finding the first `img` in the `item` each time a click happens.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. It does work fine in Bootply so I'm thinking it's something else interfering with it's function.
I've decided to use Imagepicker (https://rvera.github.io/image-picker/) instead and it worked first time.